# Make Default view as Documents instead General

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I would like to know if possible to make default view as "Documents" in Teams channel under files. As I open i see "general" as default view or first view under files, however i need to navigate to documents to see all my folders.

As my folders are located in top level not in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, we can’t set the default channel as Document instead of **General** in Teams, it is by design.

---

**[Microsoft Official Documents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-a-channel-name-in-teams-bb1761e1-bc68-4654-985d-7095cd0b2032#:%7E:text=Team%20members%20should%20go%20to,to%20change%20a%20channel%20name.&text=next%20to%20the%20channel%20name%20and%20select%20Update%20channel.)**

You can't change the name of the General channel -- that default channel is always called General and is always the first channel in the list.

---